# Spring boot, hasAnyAuthority is not working correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, role-based-access-control

In my configure(HttpSecurity) I have :

```
.antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.BANK, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
```

And in this particular endpoint :

```
public void finishPasswordReset(@RequestBody KeyAndPasswordVM keyAndPassword)
```

I put above :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(\""+AuthoritiesConstants.BANK+"\", \""+AuthoritiesConstants.USER+"\")")
```

But when I test it with and admin user with a role "ROLE_ADMIN" (who's not authorized) using postman, there's not a 403 and the request passed normally.

Information: 
    `AuthoritiesConstants.USER = "ROLE_USER";`
    `AuthoritiesConstants.BANK = "ROLE_BANK";`
    `AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";`

Comment: Did you [enable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#enableglobalmethodsecurity) global method security ?  `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: Hello, Yes it's Enabled, It's was finally a problem with session I think, when I change data in H2, for example role of particular user from simple user to Admin, it's not taken into consideration, spring get data from session cache and ignored H2 data